# Delete the last integer in an array without it becoming zero

Tags: c, arrays, queue

So I'm using an array based queue implementation.

After the array is filled, to delete the first element out, I shifted the array to the left.
This made the last element in the array zero, this also meant I can't enter a new element in to the array because the last spot is taken up by a zero.

Is there a way to completely delete the element instead of it becoming a zero?

I tried this to completely empty the queue using this, but it just turned all the elements in to zero.

```
case 3:
    memset(queue, 0, sizeof(queue));
    printf("\nThe entire queue has been emptied");
    break;
```

Thank you.

Comment: C has no concept of "empty" array element. Every element must contain something. You might choose to interpret "0" as "empty" if you like; that's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you overwrite the last element with a new value? Let's say the queue is `n` elements long and you want to overwrite the last element `array[n-1]` with a new value e.g. `23`...

```
array[n-1] = 23;
```

or

```
*(array+n-1) =23;
```

To completely delete the entry sounds like a difficult problem because you are making the array smaller, but there will still exist a bit of memory where your last element used to be. You should control your program so that it never tries to access array elements beyond the limit of your array as the results will be unpredictable.

It is really important in your code that you have a way of your program knowing how long arrays are. The computer may not stop you accessing memory beyond what is allocated for an array, but it is a very bad idea - particularly if you were to try to write to it.

So as long as you remember how long your array is all you have to do to delete the last element is reduce the length of your array by 1.